# How to use ajax callback to determine when to submit form

Tags: php, callback, onsubmit

I want to modify a form using javascript (after a user must have clicked the submit button) before I submit the it. The action involves an ajax call which must complete before I submit the form. The problem is that the `submit` event handler will finish execution and return false before the ajax will complete, and I've not been able to figure out how to submit the form after the ajax completes. Although I know that there's some other way to do this, but I want to know if there's how it can be done this way. Thanks.

```
$("form#profile").submit(function() {
    var dept;
    if (IsEmpty($("input[name=dept_id1]").val())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        dept = $("input[name=dept_id1]").val();
        $.post("funcs.php", {dept:dept}, function(d) {
            $("select[name=dept_id]").val(d);
            // It is at this point that I want to submit the form
            return true;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("form#profile").submit(function() {
    var dept;
    if (IsEmpty($("input[name=dept_id1]").val())) {
        return true;
    } else {
        dept = $("input[name=dept_id1]").val();
        $.post("funcs.php", {dept:dept}, function(d) {
            $("select[name=dept_id]").val(d);
            // It is at this point that I want to submit the form

            // unbind your submit handler
            $("form#profile").unbind('submit');

            // Optionally bind a new handler here

            // Submit it with no handler or new handler
            $("form#profile").submit();

            return true;
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Also note that instead of `$("form#profile")` you should us `$("#profile")` as it is a faster selector, and since id's should be unique it will select the same element.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the form only submits when I click the submit button twice. Any more suggestions?

Comment: I'll have to click the submit button twice before the form can submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with jquery event.preventDefault().

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

This blocks the event from being triggered. Then, you can do all the stuff you need and finally continue with the post with $.post

Here's an example (taken from jquery's site):

```
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#searchForm").submit(function(event) {

    /* stop form from submitting normally */
    event.preventDefault(); 

    /* get some values from elements on the page: */
    var $form = $( this ),
        term = $form.find( 'input[name="s"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr( 'action' );

    /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
    $.post( url, { s: term },
      function( data ) {
          var content = $( data ).find( '#content' );
          $( "#result" ).empty().append( content );
      }
    );
  });
```

Read more here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/#example-8

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Answer (score -2):

What you want to do is use `async: false` in your jquery ajax call.  You cannot do this with `$.post` but actually need to use `$.ajax` instead.  Something like this:

```
var d = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            url:    "funcs.php",
            data:   "dept="+dept,
        }).responseText;

$("select[name=dept_id]").val(d);
return true;
```